# Searching data using Text box and Drop Down with result displaying on a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Please I want a scenario where I will be able to Search data using Text box and Drop Down with result displaying on a gridview

> <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
>   CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
>
> ```
> </script>
> ```
>
> ```
>     <table>
>         <tr>
>             <td>Last Name</td>
>             <td>
>                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr>
>             <td>Speciality</td>
>             <td>
>                 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSpeciality" runat="server">
>                     <asp:ListItem Text="" />
>                     <asp:ListItem Text="ItemA" />
>                     <asp:ListItem Text="ItemB" />
>                     <asp:ListItem Text="ItemC" />
>                 </asp:DropDownList></td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr>
>             <td>Location</td>
>             <td>
>                 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocation" runat="server">
>                     <asp:ListItem Text="" />
>                     <asp:ListItem Text="Item1" />
>                     <asp:ListItem Text="Item2" />
>                     <asp:ListItem Text="Item3" />
>                 </asp:DropDownList></td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr>
>
>             <td colspan="2" align="center">
>                 <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" /></td>
>         </tr>
>     </table>
>
>
> </form> </body> </html>
> ```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string lastName = txtLastName.Text.Trim();
            string speciality = ddlSpeciality.Text;
            string location = ddlLocation.Text;
            Response.Redirect(string.Format("page2.aspx?lastname={0}&speciality={1}&location={2}",lastName ,speciality , location));


        }
    }


}
```

//OK

Comment: take a ref from [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/search-gridview-by-dropdownlist-and-textbox-value1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, at **page2.aspx** `Page_Load` event

```
string lastname = Request.QueryString["lastname"];
string location = Request.QueryString["location"];
string speciality = Request.QueryString["speciality"];
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Server=.;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True;");
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Table where lastname=@lname,location=@loc,speciality=@spec",cnn);
cnn.Open();
adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lastname);
adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loc", location);
adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spec", speciality);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Hope helps,

Comment: Don't use `AddWithValue`. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx